# Web Application and DDD

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, openaccess

I'm new to EF, I want to develop a web application to sell. I've been reading about DDD (Domain-driven design ), but I find that its implementation is complicated. Any suggestions or some project to understand this architecture.?

I plan on using as ORM: OpenAccess or NHibernate

Comment: Before starting off on DDD I'd suggest reading Vaughn Vernon's book: http://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1367772967&sr=8-1&keywords=vaughn+vernon.  You may also want to read Eric Evans': http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1367773025&sr=8-1&keywords=eric+evans.  Vaughn has some added techniques that Eric's original work does not contain.  BTW, EF is an ORM but you mention that you plan on using OpenAccess or NHibernate :)

Comment: +1 also can't recommend the Vernon book enough, I'm halfway through it myself and it's a great companion to the Evans book. If you're still investigating persistence methods, I'd strongly advise looking into NoSQL solutions as these allow for your entities to be created in a business-centric way.  I've often found with ORMs that my DB design either leaks into the entities, or I have to cut off the ORM in the persistence layer (loosing most of the ORM goodness), just to keep things architecturally clean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OpenAccess ORM [quick start scenarios section](http://help.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/quickstart-overview.html) and the product [Samples Kit](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/features/samples-kit.aspx), which contains end-to-end integration samples with different technologies. Should you have more specific questions, you could contact the product's [support team](http://www.telerik.com/support.aspx), which can guide you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch these [trainings](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/). It is step by step explanation how to create web application based on entity framework from data layer to presentation. Also you can watch plurasight trainings.

Comment: DDD NEVER starts with the database layer. that's the Data centric approach, as EF is a persistence detail.